# How to keep TypeScript types DRY

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

I've started using TypeScript in my React application but I find I'm repeating myself, especially with my `mapDispatchToProps` functions.
Is there a better way to declare the types?

I have a feeling that I may be able to access the functions types within the `this` interface `state` that is used on the async function, however, I don't know enough about TS and cant find a specific answer to this anywhere.

*index.tsx*

```
import { globalDispatchKeyData } from '../actions.tsx'
import { doSomething } from './services'

class Index extends Component {
  // I declare it here
  globalDispatchKeyData: (key: string, data: {}) => void

  constructor(props: any) {
    this.globalDispatchKeyData = this.props.globalDispatchKeyData.bind(this)
    this.doSomething = doSomething.bind(this)


    ...
  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { globalDispatchKeyData }
```

*services.tsx*

```
interface IndexState {
  // I also declare it here
  globalDispatchKeyData: (key: string, data: {}) => void
}

export async function doSomething(this: IndexState) {
   globalDispatchKeyData('TYPE', {})
}
```

Is this the only way currently to declare types for dispatch functions or am I missing something?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you want to create a type so that you dont have to use this everywhere `(key: string, data: {}) => void` ?

Comment: @AvinKavish Yeah potentially if thats the right way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a type alias for potentially any other type to avoid repeating yourself.

```
type DispatchKeyDataFn = (key: string, data: {}) => void

// Usage
globalDispatchKeyData: DispatchKeyDataFn
```

Type aliases are extremely flexible and can be used to create unions, intersections and many other things as documented here

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html (towards the bottom half)